# JSP without scriplets

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

I have a servlet which creates a collection of objects and sets that to the request object and passes it to a jsp page. In the jsp page, I use `logic:iterate` to iterate over the collection received and display it in a html table inside text boxes.

The user can edit the text boxes and when he clicks save, the data from those table (where each row represents an object) must be used to form again a collection of objects and pass that to a servlet to save that in a db. The main constraint is I should not use SCRIPLETS.

Can any help me with this?

Comment: Can you use javaScript/ java Bean?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest this

- When you click the `save` button, send the data to desired servlet by the `<form method = "POST" action = "/YourServlet">`.
- In this servlet, you can get all the request parameters and convert them to collection as per your requirement
- Save the created collection in database
- After it is done, using `RequestDispatcher` forward to your previous JSP

Answer (score -1):

Since you can't use scriptlets, your only possible solution is pure Javascript